# How to deploy Meteor App to IIS server?

Tags: meteor

I would like to deploy Meteor App to `IIS` or `IIS Node` in Windows.
Could you please help me?

Comment: In [this official Meteor page](https://www.meteor.com/install#) click the link "Using Windows?" about halfway down.  Currently it appears you need a Linux machine.  This could be a Linux virtual machine running in Oracle Virtual Box or VMWare on Windows, and Docker or Vagrant might make setup easier.

Comment: yes, but I would like to deploy Meteor App that I have built in windows to IIS server. I mean that I want host it on IIS.

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you where the Meteor team says it is not supported and asks for your email so that they can announce future support?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the only way to do that(not tested) is to build it `meteor build .` and then deploy it as a nodejs app http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx but probably you will have a "ton" of problems with nodejs dependencies.